# How to develop Android apps with Java 1.6?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have `Java 1.6` on my machine and I cannot (not allowed) to install `Java 1.7`. I've tried `Android Studio` and the `Eclipse Android plugin`. Both require `Java 1.7`.

What do I need to do to develop Android apps with `Java 1.6`?

Comment: Why can you not just get java 1.7?

Comment: School computer @BenyamEphrem

Comment: Download older version of Eclipse plugin or Android studio?

Comment: Then tell your lab in-charge to update the jdk. Or you can send a mail to the faculty member who is responsible for handling stuff for the department. I made them install jdk 8  :3

Comment: Made it more readable and easier to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

I know in Android Studio you can set the Java SDK in file -> project settings -> project - > edit under Project SDK [image]

Not sure if you need to download a different Android SDK to fit the Java version, but you can start there if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, just open Window/Preferences:

[image]

and choose your favourite Java version.